# PTP 10% Withholding

Tags: interest-rate-swap, pnl, tax

Apparently there's a [new IRS rule](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/partnership-withholding) that can be summarized as "starting January 1st, 2023, investors who are not U.S. taxpayers must withhold 10% of proceeds from the sale of PTPs (Publicly Traded Partnerships) which do not have an exception."

While I'm normally used to taxes on income or profit, this seems to be a tax on sale, so if buy and sell repeatedly PTPs, I am liable for 10% of the transaction value, possibly racking up more tax than my entire equity.

Is this correct? Or is the amount just "held", and there's a way to get back part of the money at a later date?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because taxation questions (and especially international taxation questions, a specialized field in itself) are outside the scope of Quant Finance.

Comment: @nbbo2 Do you think https://money.stackexchange.com/ would be a better site for this question? Or another place? I did consider Money StackExchange, but from speaking to non-traders, it seems a really obscure subject in that world, and I am expecting that the quant trader community might know more about it

Comment: I vote that this question is kept open. It is more applicable to Quantitative Finance than any other site, it is a very real and practical concern to have 10% of notional disappear from one's Brokerage account.

Comment: Talk to a specialist on this.